# Rails object.to_yaml without leading dashes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, yaml, psych

Every to_yaml output have three leading dashes:

```
---
a:
  b:
    c: soemthing
```

How convert object to yaml without leading dashes?

Comment: Yes, it works but i search for more convenient solution.

Comment: What is unconveinent about it? It's unclear what you are looking for.

Comment: It's kind of "magick numbers". Not beutiful and non convenient.

Answer (score 2):

Under the hood, `to_yaml` uses [Psych](https://github.com/ruby/psych) to parse and emit your data.

Though there are optional parameters you can specify ([listed here](https://github.com/ruby/psych/blob/master/lib/psych.rb#L463)), none suppress the leading dashes.

The simplest approach would be to `gsub` away the dashes.

```rb
object.to_yaml.gsub(/^---$/, "")
```

or, since Ruby 2.4, you can use `delete_prefix`, which reads a little better. I also gets rid of the remaining `\n`:

```rb
object.to_yaml.delete_prefix!("---\n")
```

Answer (score 0):

From the [YAML specification](http://www.yaml.org/spec/1.2/spec.html#id2760395):

> YAML uses three dashes (“---”) to separate directives from document content. This also serves to signal the start of a document if no directives are present.

That means: Your example starts as a valid YAML document should start. Nothing wrong with it.

Comment: I just want generate part of document.
My case - yaml writer with reusable blocks (&identifier) detection.

Comment: This doesn't answer the original question.